# WCF port issue and proxy creation

Tags: wcf

i have developed a small wcf service. which is hosted in windows form apps and start the service and it is running at the port 1645. here is the app.config entry for my service.

my service is started and when i try to create proxy putting url like **net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex** then i saw VS IDE is not being able to find the service but my service is running in same pc. after a lot of try when i change the port from 1645 to 7999 then i saw proxy was created. so i am very confuse the when port was 1645 then service was not discoverable and the moment i change the port then it started work. if there was problem related for port then how service was started at port 1645? i just could not figure out what was the actual problem. so anyone encounter this kind of problem previously then guide me what was the port related problem for 1645.

can anyone tell me what was the problem in port 1645 as a result i was repeatedly fail to create proxy. is there any tool which help me to diagnosis the port related problem for port 1645? thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="WCFService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">

<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/"/>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1648/ChatServer/"/>
  </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <endpoint address="tcp"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                  contract="ChatService.IChat"/>

 <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

 </service>
 </services>

 <behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
 <behavior name="behaviorConfig">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
 </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 <bindings>
 <netTcpBinding>
 <binding name="tcpBinding"
                 maxBufferSize="67108864"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                 openTimeout="00:00:10"
                 receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 maxConnections="100">
  <security mode="None">
  </security>
  <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"
                          maxBytesPerRead="67108864"
                          maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
  <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"/>
  </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what your problem would be, but the first tool I would use to investigate would be TCPView:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx
That way you can see if you have any processes that are already listening on that port.

Also if you are using Windows 2008 or 2012, it could be related to radius service:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731277.aspx